# Maven UML Generator

Tags: java, maven, uml

Gostaria de saber se existe algum plugin mais atual para gerar o UML das minhas classes em um projeto Maven.

A idéia seria rodar esse goal de "uml generator" no servidor de integração continua, e assim gerar os arquivos toda vez que haver alteração.

Eu pesquisei sobre o UML Graph, apiviz e PlantUML.

PlantUML e apiviz estão obsoletos e o UML Graph só funciona com a instalação do Graphviz, porém no meu servidor CI eu não tenho permissão pra instalar nada.

Existe alguma outra solução que atenda o que eu estou procurando ou é uma utopia?

Comment: Qual é seu servidor de Continuous Integration?

Comment: @guiandmad Se você esta procurando um plugin mais atual então me indique o que você esta usando  em seu projeto  Maven. Euconheço um gerador de UML mas é para o netbeans.